# killing a process in git bash

Tags: sockets, websocket, python-3.6, git-bash

I ran the following python code in my git bash for windows to create a web socket and i am unable to kill the process with ctrl + z. Even after restarting the git bash the process is running as when i tried reinstalling git bash it gave me error that **bash(PID 10436, closing required)**  :

```
import socket

host = socket.gethostname()

port = 8080

print('host: ',host,'port: ',port)

s = socket.socket()

s.bind((host,port))

print('started')

s.listen(1)

connection , address = s.accept()

print(address,"is online")
```

[image]

It would be really helpful if i could get to know the reason behind this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Killing a process is done usually with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> (not Z, which is more for background tasks)

You should try first to kill pid 16872, with `taskkill /F /pid 16872` (in a regular CMD)

Then see this [recent Python websocket example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54618267/6309) for another approach to your code.